# Obfuscation Tool for MS Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, obfuscation

What are some recommendations of tools that can obfuscate VBA code across forms, modules and class modules?

I've done a bit of research and read up here in the archives but there hasn't been anything mentioned in a while so I thought those recommendations could be outdated.

A couple of picked up from reading on other places are:

- CrunchCode
- Obfu-VBA

Also, please correct me if I'm wrong but from my understanding the simplified logic of a obfuscator is:

- Scramble the VBA code by using a defined logic (change X to Y)
- The tool creates a new workbook where the VBA code is all scrambled, but everything else remains the same.
- The tool can use the defined logic to revert back to the original VBA code (change Y to X)

Is that correct? What do I need to be looking into when selecting the 'defined logic'? I played around with CrunchCode before and there was a plethora of options but they were all foreign to me.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I build obfuscators (check my bio).  I don't build one for VBA.  As a first impression, the CrunchCode tool is rather standard in what it does to source code, but looks pretty reasonable to me.  I don't know how robust a product it is.  (I have no relationship with them).

Comment: you may have a look at this kind of tool too https://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba_tricks/vba-obfuscator.php

Comment: I used a tool called VBASH, it does vba obfuscation pretty reliably. IMHO it is better than CrunchCode and Obfu-VBA. I'd suggest giving it a try.

https://www.ayedeal.com/vbash

Comment: vbad app https://github.com/Pepitoh/VBad

Answer (score 4):

I have bought CrunchCode and beware that it doesn't support 64-bit systems. Support is really bad (no email replies whatsoever over a few weeks). The string encryption feature will screw up all your string comparisons and MsgBoxes, as decrypted strings are not the same as the originals. Recommend to avoid this product!

Answer (score 3):

My previous answer was poorly researched and as nobody else has replied I thought you deserved a better answer. Having tested CrunchCode, it appears that it obfuscates through the following techniques:

- Renaming

The number one obfuscation technique is to strip out all semantics and reduce the likelihood that any context will be inferred. This was commonly a problem in the days of assembly code when it was very hard to tell what the code was going to do unless you were familiar with it.

Upper and lower case letters, with poor spacing make it very tough to read.

- Removal of Comments

As above, this removes the chance of an understanding of the code being inferred.

- Substitution

Overloading of operators (through the use of User Defined Functions) is a useful technique. You can do this in VBA and I always remember this being a question I was given during an interview:

Sub 1:  x = z + y
Sub 2:  x = y + z

Sub 2 is proven to take longer than sub 1. Why is this?

Out of 10 interviewees, I was the only one who guessed operator overloading, so this has always stuck with me. You can make code behave very differently to how it is supposed to.  The addition symbol can be made to subtract, divide or any other number of combinations. When something this fundamental is changed in code, it is much harder to understand the source code.

- Extras

As an additional step, I would probably be tempted to add many redundant methods to the source code. Essentially pieces of code that perform pointless code based on a condition being true. This condition is never true, but because the code is difficult to read, this is hard to understand.

Essentially, it works like the very opposite of all the coding standards I've read over the last few years. Everything you are supposed to do as a developer to make you code more readable (after all we should all be writing our code for other developers not just for the machine - who cares that you can reduce that method to a single line if nobody can understand it?).

Caveat: There is no sure fire way to stop someone stealing your source code. I know of people who stopped their open source projects because people were selling compiled versions of it as their own. It's just one of those things for developers. Obfuscation will go some of the way but is not 100% guaranteed to stop a determined developer from stealing it but it is a case of making it more trouble than it is worth so they have diminishing returns (e.g. they could write the same functionality in the time it takes to reverse engineer the code).

Hope this helps - for more information check out [the YouTube video here](http://youtu.be/49s1OqkKDU0) (with very ominous sounding music!)

Comment: It is hard to tell from this, what techniques CrunchCode actually uses.

Comment: You can overload "+" in VBA?  What exactly do you code to do this?

Comment: Ah the "+" was an example of operand overloading. The point is that overloading is a technique used by obsfuscation tools. Nothing specifically about CrunchCode. Forgive me if I seem a bit flippant but I believe the best way is to download and try it?

Comment: You mean, the "+" operator as built-into VB6 acts differently based on the types of operands its gets?  OK, I understand.  I thought you were defining a new "+" operator somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Online VBScript Obfuscator (Encrypt/Protect VBS)

> Using this handy VBS tool, you can convert your VBScript into an
>   obfuscated VBS source code, without compromising/altering the
>   scripting functionalities and the VBScript keywords. This Free
>   VBScript Obfuscator works by converting each character in your VBS
>   source code into a much obfuscated format. Then these obfuscated
>   letters are combined at runtime and be executed via the Execute
>   function.

https://isvbscriptdead.com/vbs-obfuscator/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont mind some copy and pasting and double checking the product vbobfuscator seems to be nice. Does both vba and vbscript. Changes var and function names. www.vbobfuscator.net . Obfuscation is way more complex than a simple find and replace... that will deliver non working code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add that a tool called "VBASH" (www.ayedeal.com/vbash) can do the job. I have been using it for a while and am happy with it so far.